# How to authenticate and clone a remote repository in TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am trying to clone a repo on a remote Ubuntu server to my local Windows file system. Never done this before. I have TortoiseHg 0.9.3. I right-click and empty folder and in the TortoiseHg flyout I select "Clone". I enter `ssh://myusername@mydomain.org/test` as the source path (that's where my repo is) and the current location as the destination path. Then I hit "clone".

TortoiseHg says:

```
running ""C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\TortoisePlink.exe" -ssh -2
myuser@mydomain.org "hg -R test serve --stdio"" ... no suitable
response from remote hg  [command interrupted]
```

I then get a popup from PuTTY: "Network error: connection timed out".

Where did I go wrong? I was never asked for my password. Where do I enter that?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem by upgrading TortoiseHg from 0.9.3 to 2.6.x